# What are some good websites to get statistics on Champion and their builds?

Tags: league-of-legends

Anyone know a common website people use for builds and is it trustworthy for gameplay?

Comment: Hi @funnybob. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close your question because it is off-topic as per the [FAQ]. Questions asking for website recommendations are not allowed here because they invite 1-website-per-answer type answers, list maintenance issues (new websites opening, others dying), and problems with inaccurate voting schemes (people upvoting what they like rather than what constitutes a quality answer). If you wish to join [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) to discuss or ask there, you are welcome to once you acquire 20 rep.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular and most generally accepted by the community is [SoloMid.net](http://solomid.net/). The reason for this strong community acceptance is its Approved/Featured Guides system - guides are submitted by community members (including professional players), and from there, they are Approved by site administrators if found to be of good quality, and Featured if found to be of particularly good quality or are written by a professional player renowned for their expertise in that role or champion.

There are less popular/less rigorously vetted sites such as [LoLPro](http://www.lolpro.com/) and [Mobafire](http://www.mobafire.com/), but their content is not considered to be as "definitive" as SoloMid's. Most veteran players will suggest SoloMid as a resource, due to the heavy influence from professional League players.

Answer (score 1):

Most used website for builds and champion info is [mobafire](http://www.loldb.gameguyz.com/).

Best LoL sites:

1. [LoLDB](http://www.loldb.gameguyz.com/) Great site known for its in depth statistics, though not as good as Solomid for guides
2. [Mobafire](http://www.mobafire.com/) (Best site for countless builds for each champion as well as champion info)
3. [League of Legends wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki) (Contains champion info,info for every patch,and everything else LoL related,but does not contain builds)
4. [Leaguecraft](http://leaguecraft.com/) (contains custom skins,champion info and guides for each champion)

Answer (score 0):

mobafire.com? I would think they're a good start but the League of Legends Community might have a different opinion on it

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the stats and information about abilities and such, I would suggest using the Wikia. For building a champion and viewing other people's builds, I would suggest Leaguecraft.

Sources: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/

http://www.leaguecraft.com